# i5 12450H vs Ryzen 7 5800H

Tags: laptop, intel, ryzen

So I'm a computer science major and i've been looking for a new laptop. The HP victus which comes in 2 variants i5 12450H and ryzen 7 5800H caught my eye. Which one would you recommend

Adding in the extra price for ram for ryzen variant the price is pretty much the same

I5 12th gen: https://amzn.eu/d/iXObpN3

And ryzen 7: https://amzn.eu/d/12JXlus

I'm primarily gonna be using it for some basic to intermediate coding

Beginner type machine learning maybe

And occasional valorant